# Moving GridView with finger

Tags: android

I need a solution for the following problem :

i have a screen with vertical half portion having Linear Layout with content and lower half portion is having Grid View of Images(Tiled Area).

When finger makes contact with the tiled area and starts swiping upward, the tiled area moves upward at the same pace as the finger is moving - showing more picture below, while slowly covering white section above. After it cover the whole screen, the user can go scroll up and down swipes.

the opposite also applies: if the entire screen is covered with the tiles, and the top of the tile is already at the top of the screen, then further downward swipes will result in the opposite effect, ultimately shrinking(at the same pace as the finger is moving) the tiled area to its original size.

**NOTE : view will move at the same pace as the finger moves. i think it will be done by gesture detector**

Comment: When it covers the whole screen, the user can scroll by swiping up and down, but the view shall also shrink when swiping down ... that doesn't fit.

Comment: Hello @ElDuderino , thanks for your reply. actually when the top of the row will be at the top then further downward swipe will result in shrinking.